# Web API not adding Controller, Sqlite error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, .net-core, controller

I have a .Net Core 2.2 application, I made migrations and updated the database successfully, I want to add an API Controller with actions using Entity Framework Core, but it won't scaffold successfully. I made a similar application before this and it generated controllers fine, I'm not sure what the issue is and I tried solving it myself, but couldn't find a solution.

In the package console I get this info:

unrecognized option '--useSqlite'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.HandleUnexpectedArg(CommandLineApplication command, String[] args, Int32 index, String argTypeName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

I have tried uninstalling sqlite NuGetpackage but I still get the error, I tried rebuilding the app and restarting Visual Code, but it still doesn't work.

Here are my files

Startup.cs

```
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddDbContext<LoanContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "connectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "server=(local)\\sqlite;Database=TestDB;User Id=sa;Password=LovelyWorld1;"
  }
}
```

Loan.cs

```
 public class Loan
    {
        [Key]

        public int Details { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
        [Required]

        public string LoanID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]

        public string BorrowerName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]

        public string FundingAmount { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]

        public string RepaymentAmount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: you seem using SQLite but the connection string is for a database server like SQL server. Do you have this project on GitHub or somewhere I could check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is in your loan model attributes.
They are not in the correct place. for example, I think the key attribute should be on top of the **LoadID**. Also, the loadID is a string and I think it should be int instead. I changed the model like this:

```cs
 public class Loan
    {
        [Key] 
        public int LoanID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)"), Required]
        public string Details { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")] 
        public string BorrowerName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")] 
        public string FundingAmount { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")] 
        public string RepaymentAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I deleted your init migration and added a new one. I tested that migration with SQL server and SQLite and it was fine. 
Just be sure when you are using slite you should set the connection string like this

> "Data Source=loanDb.db"

**note:** It is better to use decimal for "FundingAmount" and "RepaymentAmount" fields instead of string.